# How can one cause a property of one class to update when another is updated?

Tags: vb.net, oop

Suppose you have the following three classes:

```
Public Class SpecialJob : Inherits Job
   Public Property Details As List(Of Detail)
   Public Property JobTotals As Totals
End Class

Public Class SpecialDetail : Inherits Detail
   Public Property DetailTotals As Totals
   Public Property DocNum As String
   Public Property Reference As String
End Class

Public Class Totals
   Public Property Expense As Decimal
      Get
         Return tExpense
      End Get
      Set(value As Decimal)
         TotalExpense -= tExpense
         tExpense = value
         TotalExpense += tExpense
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Property Tax As Decimal
      Get
         Return tTax
      End Get
      Set(value As Decimal)
         TotalExpense -= tTax
         tTax = value
         TotalExpense += tTax
      End Set
   End Property

   Public Property TotalExpense As Decimal
End Class
```

How could one implement a solution such that updating the Expense of the Detail class also updates the Expense of the Job class?

EDIT:
There are many other properties and functions in each class. I only put a few to demonstrate the basic structure.

Comment: This sounds a good place for the Observer Pattern. In Summary you will have an Observer and a Subject where the Subject will "subscribe" to an Observer. So every time the Subject gets updated, the subject will send a message to the observer. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817669.aspx

Comment: Since the `Job` is the owner of the `Detail`, you can have it subscribe to an event on each `Detail` that will be raised when the `Expense` updates.  It would probably make sense to have all of them pass through a single handler, which you can do using `AddHandler`.  Make sure you use `Option Strict`, otherwise you will silently get subscriptions that can't be unsubscribed if you don't get the handler signature exactly right.

Comment: I appreciate the input. Both are options I had tried to various degrees. I had only hoped there might be some simpler solution that I was missing!